# How to clear ng-show validation message on clear button click

Tags: html, angularjs

I am checking the input field with validation and showing validation message like "contact person field accept only characters" If I click cancel button It will close the popup. Again, If I open the same popup to add new data already shown ng-show validation message is still displaying. Validation Message is not clearing. How to clear ng-show validation messages in cancel button click

I have used form.inputname="" to clear the form input values. But How do I clear
validation messages in angularjs

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code here MyForm is form name. And place Submitted to your ng-show condition with **&&** operator in validation message in html code

```
 $scope.Submitted = false;
 $scope.MyForm.$rollbackViewValue();
 $scope.MyForm.$setSubmitted();
 $scope.MyForm.$setPristine();
 $scope.MyForm.$setUntouched();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<button type ="button" ng-click="hideNotifications()" >Cancel </button>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.hideNotifications = function () {
  $scope.message = false;
  }
```